# EXT4-fs: previous I/O error to superblock detected

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, ext4

i have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my usb hdd. The problem i am getting is this:

ext4 (sdb6): previous i/o error to superblock detected
buffer erronr on device sdb6. logical block 0

I have been told to do fsck on this drive, which i did. Only one bad sector was found and made "unavailable".

Also, I am pretty sure this issue has nothing to do with bad sectors / blocks since the hdd is new and there hasn't been any physical damage.

What comes to my mind is that the issue could be on the line of 
1. "spin down" (i just recently found out about this) or 
2. the kernel dropping the usb connection.

Any help and ideas on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

-Tyyr

EDIT 1: At this point, i am using indicator-cpu-freq set to performance (as opposed to ondemand as before). It's stable but still, not a true solution.

Comment: just ran into this exact problem. it was a mistake to close it. thanks...